# How to plot a namespace on AWS Cloudwatch Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

In AWS Cloudwatch dashboard.  I want to add a widget that plots all the metrics within the namespace.

I have multiple instances reporting a metric, but they belong to a scaling group.  So I cannot plot the metric for an specific instance since that instance may be terminated and reported by another one.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch relies on instance ids to read out the metrics for the instance. That is exactly the reason we had to develop our own solution [CloudWatch envimation](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B079VCQ2T8)

It gives you the possibility to generate dashboards based on instance names as well as Autoscaling group names.

This [blog post](https://blog.envimate.com/aws-native-monitoring-using-cloudwatch-dashboards/) describes the issue you are facing in more details

Hope this helps.

Nune